# How To Not setValue To Google Sheet When There Is Unfilled Field On The Form?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I'm trying to make an update form (contain 'Name' & 'Gender' field) that could update current values in the cell A1 or B1 in Google Sheet. But the thing is with my code when user only wanna update for example 'Name' which is in cell 'A1' and then submit it, the existing value of 'Gender' in cell 'B1' become blank because user only submit the 'Name' field.

Is there a way to make the unfilled field not rewrite the current value into blank? Your response will be appreciated :)

Here's my code:

```
function update(formObject) {
  var url =  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('url');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

  ws.getRange('A1').setValue(formObject.name);  
  ws.getRange('B1').setValue(formObject.gender);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function update(obj) {
  const url=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('url');
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  const ws=ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  if(obj.name)ws.getRange('A1').setValue(obj.name);
  if(obj.gender)ws.getRange('B1').setValue(obj.gender);
}
```